# Pre-processor commands (#if defined) not working in CUDA program?

Tags: c, cuda, c-preprocessor, nvcc

In this code snippet, I would expect the "printf" command inside the MatrixMultiplication() method to display its text.  It does not, even though "size" has been declared on the previous line and "test" is set to 1.  Here's the code:

```
void MatrixMultiplication(float * M, float * N, float * P, int Width, int test)
{
        int size = Width * Width * sizeof(float);

        #if defined size
        if (test)
        {
                printf("Should be equal to %d.  Int size:%d", Width * Width * sizeof(float), size);
        }
        #endif
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{

        // Omitted for brevity...

        int test = 1;                                                   

        // Omitted for brevity...

        MatrixMultiplication(hostM, hostN, reference, atoi(matrix_id), test);

        // Omitted for brevity...

}
```

I'm compiling with this command:

```
nvcc -I/home/sbu/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc -L/home/sbu/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib -o matrixmul matrixmul.cu -lcutil_x86_64
```

Is there something about nvcc that makes this sort of "#if defined" command not work?  I've used this sort of syntax before in native **C** and C++ code using gcc and it worked just fine.

Any illumination on this issue would be great!

Here is the full code on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/SusnpgFc

Comment: I tested your claim that this works on gcc.  It did not work for me on gcc 4.1.2/RHEL 5.5

Comment: I was referring to the "#if defined" command, not this code snippet.  I'll make my question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Yes, I didn't test your code snippet on gcc.  I wrote my own with an #if defined that was testing for a variable as opposed to a preprocessor macro.  It does not work on gcc.  Or if you like, pastebin something that demonstrates what you think works on gcc but not on nvcc, or add it to the question.  This presumably could be a very short piece of code with no actual cuda constructs in it at all, I would think.

Comment: Sadly, your suggestion made me go back and look at the code I thought I had working and I see that you're right.  It behaves the same as this code.  Seems like I got confused by some of my own test output.

So is there any way to do what I'm attempting here - to check for a variable being declared and act only if that variable exists?

Comment: You could define a global variable `char size` and then use the condition `if (sizeof(size) != sizeof(char))`. However how that is going to help your students understand the code I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It does not, even though "size" has been declared on the previous line

The `#if defined size` tests whether a preprocessor macro with that name has been defined, it does not check whether a variable with that name is declared in the program.

It will only evaluate to true if you have a `#define size` or `#define size some replacement tokens` before that.

Comment: Thank you!  Is there any way to check whether or not a variable named 'size' has been declared in the program?  I understand this is an unusual request.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you try to use `size`, and it isn't declared in the current scope, you'll get a compilation error. But that probably isn't what you're after. You can grep the source to check, but that probably isn't either. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: You could make it a static global variable with a value that indicates whether or not you want to take the conditional action (such as printf...).  Then instead of saying #if defined you just use a regular C if statement: if (test != 0) printf...

Comment: It's for training purposes.  What I want is to have code that a student can go through and add a line at a time.  Then, if they have defined an int named "size", the code that is looking for such a variable will execute and output what "size" SHOULD be and what it actually is.  But if a "size" integer hasn't been defined, the code won't break at compilation.

Basically, IF an integer 'size' has been declared AND the 'test' flag has been set, THEN output whatever debug text I want.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do that without writing your own preprocessor, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing is done before the compilation. So when preprocessor checks this:

```
#if defined size
```

`size` is not defined anywhere, so it's replaced with `0`. Hence the whole `if` code segment will not removed before passing to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks!  Please see the follow-up question I posted on Daniel Fischer's answer.

Comment: @user1644184 No, you can't. `size` variable is known to preprocessor. What you can do is check if `size` has a value set to it using an `if`.